# Edit CV / Articles & Blogs / Can't edit URL

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

I was looking over my CV and saw that some of my writing on 3rd party sites have broken links.  They changed URL structure and didn't redirect the links.  I wanted to update the URLs, but editing the record doesn't allow it.

Comment: [*Stack Overflow Jobs* and *Developer Story* was closed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/415293/sunsetting-jobs-developer-story) down in the beginning of 2022. And from the 2022-10-22 [The Verge article](https://www.theverge.com/23421320/stack-overflow-ceo-interview-prashanth-chandrasekar-software-engineering-microsoft): *"When I joined the company, we were really sort of accelerating our SaaS business both in 2019, 2020. We pivoted away from that old talent, job listings business that I mentioned earlier, as we actually closed that business."*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We now allow editing writings URLs.

Thanks for the report!