# Can't edit URL link to Apps & Software projects in Developer CV

Tags: support, feature-request

I was going over my Developer CV and noticed that the link to one of my projects listed under the **Apps & Software** section was out of date (the location of the project has since moved). However when I go to edit the listing for my project there is no field for modifying the URL.

[There's a similar question here regarding items under the Articles & Blogs section](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/314626/edit-cv-articles-blogs-cant-edit-url).

**Am I missing something or is this another case of the issue above?** Sure it's easy for me to create a new project listing with the updated URL but it would make a heck of a lot more sense to just add this as an editable field.